# Symfony twig namespaces for bundles

Tags: php, symfony, twig

does anyone know how I can add twig paths (the path where Symfony looks for templates) dynamically for bundles?

I found that in the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#template-namespaces.

The hardcoded way would look something like that

```
twig:
    paths:
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/composerNamespace/bundleName/templates'
```

But I would like to tell Symfony to check the `/templates` directory of every enabled bundle without explicitly writing it in the config.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: `bin/console debug:twig` will show you the current paths.  Using the older bundle format, bundle/Resources/views is automatically added.  I don't have a test case handy but I suspect that bundles using the new directory format probably have templates added automatically assuming the directory exists.

Comment: In the same link of the documentation you've linked, you can see an example on how to add the paths with `PHP`. Doesn't this help you?